# Accesing data from Roles into gridview

Tags: asp.net, roles

Is it possible to retrieve the user details into **grid view**, from Roles assigned through **Administrator website**?
Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve same kind of thing by making the extra column of roles in the database and extracting the value of role during the time of login.

Now you can store this role in any kind of variables like cookies ,sessions etc and performing the following check in the masterpage

```
if(session[role]==null)
{
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}

else if(session[role]!="User")
{
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```